# Parameters in the HTTP request

Tags: 8, entities

I am trying to render a block depending on the parameter(entity) present in the requested page. Suppose if I am on a url like this: `http://localhost/drupal8/user/1` then a block with label user is created. Same thing I am trying to achieve for other urls like `http://localhost/drupal8/node/1`, `http://localhost/drupal8/comment/1`. I am using this piece of code:

`if ($this->request->attributes->has($entity_type)) {
   return code for rendering block
 }`

(here $entity_type will be replaced by user,comment,node) to check whether requested page has a particular key. This piece of code works for checking keys like node and user when I am on page `http://localhost/drupal8/node/1` and `http://localhost/drupal8/user/1` respectively but when I am on page like `http://localhost/drupal8/comment/1` and check for key: 'comment' then it returns `FALSE` because it is not defined. Is this an expected behaviour, if yes then what should I do to solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: You can have a look at array_keys($this->request->attributes->all()) to see what kind of entries exists

Comment: @DanielWehner , I have already done that to know whether `comment` exists as a key. It doesn't exist as key hence I am not able to get an instance of comment entity (by using `$this->request->attributes->all()`) which I need to render block content. I hope u have understood my problem.

Comment: sorry mistyped in above comment above: (by using `$this->request->attributes->get()`).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of inspecting the request object directly, the `current_route_match` service is the preferred object to consult for request parameters. It provides both the raw and upcast values of parameters. Additionally, using `\Drupal\Core\Routing\StackedRouteMatchInterface` you can retrieve values from the master request.

The reason you are having trouble with `/comment/{comment}` is because that route is special: it performs a subrequest to view the entity the comment belongs to. This explains why you only have the node entity available when viewing a comment on a node.

To work around this, consult the master request:

```
$comment = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getMasterRouteMatch()->getParameter('comment');
```